# Where to Buy Soft Matzah?

Tags: product-recommendation, passover, matzah

Does any one know where I can buy Kosher Lemehadrin soft Matzos (like the ones the Teimanim eat) in the New York area?

Answer (score 3):

I found an online source for soft matzos as below. I could not find details about a living  Rabbi Mordechai Maslaton; you will need to check the supervision.

> http://softmatza.com/index.php/soft-matza.html
>
> All Soft Matza is baked under the Strict Supervision of Rabbi
> Mordechai Maslaton of Keter Sion Torah Center in Brooklyn, NY. Each
> Matza is personally checked and certified by Rabbi Maslaton.

Comment: Rabbi Maslaton was nifter in 2014, I was at his levaya. I wonder who supervises them now...